# using xmlhttprequest with POST gives "Unexpected end of input"

Tags: javascript

I am trying to use xmlhttprequest using POST but it gives me the error "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input " any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

```
xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (xhr.readyState === 4 && xhr.status === 200) {
        console.log("saved data!");
    }
}

xhr.open("POST", "http://website.com/login.php", true);
xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
xhr.send("user=ben&pass=abcxyz");
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure this would not be the problem, but you should be using `encodeURIComponent` on the argument passed to `xhr.send`

Comment: Also, is `"http://website.com/login.php"` in the same domain as your website?

Comment: Also, maybe put `console.log(xhr.readyState + ", " + xhr.status)` as the first line of your `onreadystatechange` function, to see how far the process gets. It might be a problem with what your PHP is returning.

Comment: also i added `header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');` in the php file to allow cross domain access.

Comment: @ianpgall if i just remove the parameters and add the full url like this `http://website.com/login.php?user=ben&pass=abcxyz` it works but i dont know how save that is

Comment: There's nothing wrong with the code you've posted - I tried pasting it into a test page and it worked fine. The problem must be from elsewhere in your code, or maybe within the JavaScript that the PHP file is returning. Is it possible to paste the entire script here?